# Include Folder in Parent Directory

Tags: path, directory, jekyll

I wanted to hide the Jekyll directory from my repo. It creates a lot of folders and is quite confusing.

I've moved Jekyll into its own directory. I want to include a folder full of markdown pages in the parent directory of Jekyll. They're all inside `inc_folder`.

Here's my directory structure.

```
[inc_folder]
    contact-me.markdown
    about.markdown
[jekyll]
    [_data]
    [_sass] (... etc)
_config.yml
```

In `_config.yml`:

```
source: ./jekyll/
include: ['./inc_folder/']

destination will build to wherever but i don't care! I want include!
# destination: ../../test/
```

I run `./jekyll build` and it it will not include the `inc_folder` when rendering.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `include` folder MUST be in the `source` folder. There's no way to get around this.

Reading [include tag code](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb#L148), you can see that it uses [a method](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/site.rb#L353) that prepends source folder to include folder.

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll handles relative links a little unintuitively. With `include: ['./inc_folder/']` it is looking for `inc_folder` at `./Jekyll/inc_folder/`.

Try changing the path to `include: ['../inc_folder/']`. If that doesn't work, try making it an absolute link.